# CDF of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity, random-variables, density-function

We have a probability function

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
|x| & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

In the book says that the CDF is:

$$
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x \leq -1\\
(1-x^2)/2 & -1 \leq x < 0\\
(1+x^2)/2 & 0 \leq x < 1\\
1 & x\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

What was the procedure to get that?

Comment: You mean the *cumulative* distribution function, right?

Comment: @Lovsovs: usually "distribution function" means the cdf, while "density function" means pdf. $\text{Distribution}\neq\text{Density}$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yes, that was what I was trying to clarify (that $F(x)$ is the CDF), but what makes you think that I would confuse distribution and density?

Comment: @Lovsovs: My point was that there was no need for clarification, and I thought the only reason you could request clarification is that you thought "distribution function" might possibly mean either pdf or cdf. In the math literature "distribution function" always refers to the cdf.

Comment: @symplectomorphic All right, thanks for the info! :)

Comment: @Lovsovs: no problem, it's unfortunate that the "d" in pdf and the "d" in cdf mean different things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt.$$

As the function $f$ is zero on $[-\infty,-1]$, we have $F(x) = 0, \forall x \le -1$. 
For $x\in[-1,0]$ we have $|x| = -x$, so

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt = \int_{-1}^xf(t)dt = -\int_{-1}^xtdt = -\frac12t^2\bigg\vert_{-1}^x = \frac12 - \frac{x^2}2.$$

For $x\in[0,1]$ we have $|x| = x$, so
$$F(x) = \int_{-1}^xf(t)dt = \int_{-1}^0f(t)dt + \int_{0}^xf(t)dt = F(0) +  \frac12t^2\bigg\vert_0^x = \frac12 + \frac{x^2}2.$$

And having $f(x) = 0$ on $x>1 $ equals to $F(x) = 1$ for this values.

Comment: I get -1/2 t^2 and 1/2 t^2 that you got, but I dont understand the evaluation, I see that you evaluated the intervals, -1 first and then x.

Comment: @ColonelG, use the property of definite integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^cf(x)dx + \int_c^bf(x)dx$. Then consecutively find $F(x)$ in different regions. First on $(-\infty,-1)$, then use this result to find it on $[-1,0]$, then use the last result to find it on $[0,1]$ and etc.